# Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism at javax.crypto.JceSecurity in JavaCompiler API

Tags: ssh, cryptography, jsch, java-security, java-compiler-api

I am trying to connect to SSH (Unix environment) using the JSch library in JavaCompiler API. I can connect to the unix environment through a normal Java program but cannot from JavaCompiler API.

Looks like it is related to crypto.policy Cipher length error but I am not sure how to solve it in JavaCompiler API.

Stuck for 2 Days....

Complete Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at dummy.dummy_Main.main(dummy_Main.java:324)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:518)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.jce.AES256CTR.init(AES256CTR.java:56)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkCipher(Session.java:2497)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkCiphers(Session.java:2474)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.send_kexinit(Session.java:624)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:307)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
        at test.Test.bpmUnlock(Test.java:180)
        at test.Test.start(Test.java:221)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
        at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:93)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot locate policy or framework files!
        at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:316)
        at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(JceSecurity.java:50)
        at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:85)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:82)
        ... 14 more
```

Sample code:(Ignore if any compile error)

```java
package dummy;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.Security;

import java.util.Vector;


import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;


import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;



public class dummy_Main{
    //supportive variables
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        
        //String source = masterVector.get(0).get(15);
        
        String source = "package test;\r\n"
                + "//jsch library\r\n"
                + "import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;\r\n"
                + "import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;\r\n"
                + "import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;\r\n"
                + "import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "//Security\r\n"
                + "import java.security.Security;\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "public class Test{\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "    public List<Object> bpmUnlock(String incident, Vector<String> RPA_SEARCH_CRITERIA,Vector<String> INCIDENT_INFO) throws Exception{\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "                    try {\r\n"
                + "                        System.out.println(\"JSCH Not loaded.\");\r\n"
                + "                        JSch connect = new JSch();\r\n"
                + "                        System.out.println(\"JSCH loaded.\");\r\n"
                + "                        Session session = connect.getSession(user,host,port);\r\n"
                + "                        session.setPassword(pass);\r\n"
                + "                        System.out.println(\"password set\");\r\n"
                + "                        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); \r\n"
                + "                        config.put(\"StrictHostKeyChecking\", \"no\");\r\n"
                + "                        session.setConfig(config);\r\n"
                + "                        System.out.println(\"COnfig Set\");\r\n"
                + "                        session.connect();\r\n"
                + "                        System.out.println(\"session connect\");\r\n"
                + "                        Channel channel=session.openChannel(\"exec\");\r\n"
                + "                        \r\n"
                + "                        System.out.println(\"channel opened\");\r\n"
                + "                        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(\"echo \\\"Hello\\\"\");\r\n"
                + "                        Thread.sleep(5000);\r\n"
                + "                        channel.connect();\r\n"
                + "                        System.out.println(\"channel connected.\");\r\n"
                + "                        \r\n"
                + "                        channel.disconnect();\r\n"
                + "                        session.disconnect();\r\n"
                + "                        File f = new File(\"User_unlock_script_executed.txt\");\r\n"
                + "                        f.createNewFile();\r\n"
                + "                        FileWriter w = new FileWriter(f);\r\n"
                + "                        w.close();\r\n"
                + "                    }\r\n"
                + "                    catch (Exception e) {\r\n"
                + "                        // TODO: handle exception\r\n"
                + "                        System.out.println(e.toString());\r\n"
                + "                    }\r\n"
                + "                }\r\n"
                + "            }\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "            //RPA_SEARCH_CRITERIA.set(16, resolution);\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "            //0 : For movement keep 0\r\n"
                + "            //1 : For resolve keep 1\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "            infoObjects = Arrays.asList(incident,RPA_SEARCH_CRITERIA,INCIDENT_INFO,0);\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "            return infoObjects;\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "        } catch (Exception e) {\r\n"
                + "            System.out.println(\"In BPM UNLOCK FUNCTION :\"+e);\r\n"
                + "            return infoObjects;\r\n"
                + "        }\r\n"
                + "    }\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "    public List<Object> start(String incident, Vector<String> RPA_SEARCH_CRITERIA,Vector<String> INCIDENT_INFO) throws Exception{\r\n"
                + "        return bpmUnlock(incident,RPA_SEARCH_CRITERIA,INCIDENT_INFO);\r\n"
                + "    }\r\n"
                + "}";
        
        
        //try {
            
            File root = new File("/java");
            
            File sourceFile = new File(root,"test/Test.java");
            sourceFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            
            Files.write(sourceFile.toPath(), source.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            
            
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            Object obj = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("config.json"));
            
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)obj;
            
            String name = (String)jsonObject.get("JDK_PATH");
            
            System.out.println(name);
            
            
            System.setProperty("java.home", name);
            //System.setProperty("java.home", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-18.0.2");
            
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
            
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));
            
            Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");
            
            JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
            System.out.println(ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler());
            System.out.println(sourceFile.getPath());
            int flag = compiler.run(null, null, null, sourceFile.getPath());
            System.out.println(flag);
            if(flag == 0) {
                System.out.println("Compilation successful.");
                
                URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {root.toURI().toURL()});
                
                Class<?> cls = Class.forName("test.Test",true,classLoader);
                
                Object instance = cls.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
                
                Method startMethod = instance.getClass().getMethod("start",String.class,Vector.class,Vector.class);
                
                Vector<String> v = new Vector<>();
                Vector<String> l = new Vector<>();
                v.add("sarage");
                l.add("sarage");
                
                
                startMethod.invoke(instance,"",v,l);
                //System.out.println(startMethod.invoke(instance,"",v,l));
                
            }
//      }
//      catch (Exception e) {
//          System.out.println("In JavaCompiler Error:\n"+e);
//      }
    }
}
```

I tried setting : `Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");`

I tried adding `crypto.policy=unlimited` in `java.security` file

Also tried adding `local_policy.jar` and US_export_policy `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_301\\lib\\security` folder

Comment: It worked for me after setting System.setProperty("java.home", "PATH TO JDK 18") and restarting command prompt.;

Comment: Makes sense, but these properties are usually meant to be read only as you don't know when they will be read out, usually during system startup. This is why there is generally something like a `-D` parameter for the command line program such as `java` / `javaw`.

Comment: oh yes, thanks for the additional info.

Comment: Thank me when the application doesn't crash when the runtime gets updated ;)

Comment: Yes, @MaartenBodewes we can provide these values through the command line or can make it configurable.